# Variadic deduction guide not taken by g++, taken by clang++ - who is correct?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct list
{
    template <typename... Args>
    list(Args...) 
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Types) > 0);
    }
};

template <typename... Args>
list(Args...) -> list<Args...>;

int main()
{
    list l{0, 0.1, 'a'};
}
```

I would expect `decltype(l)` to be `list<int, double, char>`. Unfortunately, *g++ 7.2* and *g++ trunk* fail the static assertion. *clang++ 5.0.0* and *clang++ trunk* compile and work as expected.

[**godbolt.org conformance view**](https://godbolt.org/g/XScFjS)

Is this a *g++* bug? Or Is there a reason why the *deduction guide* should not be followed here?

---

Adding a SFINAE constraint on the constructor seems to provide the desired behavior:

```
template <typename... Args, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == sizeof...(Types)>>
list(Args...) 
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Types) > 0);
}
```

[**godbolt.org conformance view**](https://godbolt.org/g/Kk5fJH)

Comment: I think your code might be ill-formed... for `sizeof...(Types) == 0` there is no viable instantiation of your templated constructor...

Comment: I'm struggling to see this as anything other than a gcc bug. using the previous method of a make_list() function works fine.
https://godbolt.org/g/vag3rD

Comment: @RichardHodges naturally with your method g++ doesn't try to instantiate `list<>`.

Comment: Hmm. When doing the overload resolution, there's also a hypothetical function `template<typename... Types, typename... Args> list<Types...> deducer(Args...);` - which is more specialized than the deduction guide's `template<typename.... Args> list<Args...> deducer(Args...);` isn't it?

Comment: No wait, I guess neither is more specialized...

Comment: @n.m. Why would the compiler try to instanciate list<> at all? it's not indicated.

Comment: @RichardHodges Long shot but doesn't this: [\[temp.inst\]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#7) suggest that it can instantiate anything?

Comment: also replacing the guide with `template <typename T,typename... Args> list(T,Args...) -> list<T,Args...>;` seems providing the desired behavior, giving a more specialized version of the implicit function mentioned by @aschepler

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [gcc bug 80871](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80871). The issue is, we end up with this set of candidates for deduction:

```
template <class... Types, class... Args>
list<Types...> __f(Args... ); // constructor

template <class... Args>
list<Args...>  __f(Args... ); // deduction-guide
```

Both are valid (`Types...` can deduce as empty in the first case), but the call here should be ambiguous - neither is more specialized than the other. `Types...` does not participate in ordering here (similar to the example in [[temp.deduct.partial]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#12)). So the correct behavior is to proceed to the next tiebreaker, which [favors deduction-guides](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.10). Hence, this should be a `list<int, double, char>`.

However, gcc's behavior is to favor the constructor, hence the `static_assert` triggers becuase `Types...` would indeed be empty in that situation.