# Template member variables depending on rules

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

in following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct Container
{
  std::string id;
  T value;

  Container(std::string id, T value) : id(id), value(value) {}
};

template<typename... T>
struct ElementCodec
{
  std::tuple<T...> values;

  ElementCodec(T... args) : values(args...) {}
};

template<typename... T> ElementCodec(T...) -> ElementCodec<T...>;

int main()
{
  ElementCodec a { int { 5 }, double { 3. }, Container { "52", 7 } };
  auto [x, y, container] = a.values;

  std::cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << container.value << '\n';

}
```

After the specialization of the given code the tuple `values` is of type `std::tuple<int, double, Container<int>>`. What I'd like to do is decaying it to the type stored in the container, so `std::tuple<int, double, int>` to make th access via `container.value` not necessary.

Is this possible to do in c++17? I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't really find any ressources about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could unwrap the `Container<T>`s with a helper function:

```
template <typename T> T unwrap(T value)        { return value; }
template <typename T> T unwrap(Container<T> c) { return c.value; }

template <typename T> using unwrap_t = decltype(unwrap(std::declval<T>()));
```

And then adjust your template and deduction guide accordingly:

```
template <typename... T>
struct ElementCodec
{
  std::tuple<T...> values;

  template <typename... Us>
  ElementCodec(Us... args) : values(unwrap(args)...) {}
};

template<typename... T>
ElementCodec(T...) -> ElementCodec<unwrap_t<T>...>;
```

---

The above doesn't work on gcc (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46849956/2069064)) , you can fix it with a constraint:

```
template <typename... Us,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<
    std::tuple<T...>, unwrap_t<Us>...
    >, int> = 0>
ElementCodec(Us... args) : values(unwrap(args)...) {}
```

Comment: thank you, this works. However, I don't really understand what you're doing on the gcc-bug-fix. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: It's called sfinae. It's quite a rabbit hole. Search for `std::enable_if`

Comment: @user3520616 Read the linked answer, and consider what effects the constraint has on the relevant candidates.